# Calculate distance between two points on a map with osmnx

Tags: python, routes, osmnx

I have the following code to calculate the shortest route between two points on a map. The main problem is that the shortest_path function of networkx, returns the same node for both points. The version I am emulating is based on the following link: https://towardsdatascience.com/visualization-in-python-finding-routes-between-points-2d97d4881996

It seems that the get_nearest_node function no longer exists.

How could I fix it?

```
    import networkx as nx
    import osmnx as ox
    
    graph_area = 'San Francisco, California, United States'
    mode = 'drive'
    
    # Create the graph of the area from OSM data. It will download the data and create the graph
    G = ox.graph_from_place(graph_area, network_type=mode)
    
    # OSM data are sometime incomplete so we use the speed module of osmnx to add missing edge speeds and travel times
    G = ox.add_edge_speeds(G)
    G = ox.add_edge_travel_times(G)
    
    # Save graph to disk if you want to reuse it
    #ox.save_graphml(G, "SanFrancisco.graphml")
    
    
    #G = ox.load_graphml("SanFrancisco.graphml")
    
    # Plot the graph
    fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, figsize=(10, 10), node_size=0, edge_color='y', edge_linewidth=0.2)
    
    start_latlng = (37.7824, -122.4461)
    end_latlng = (37.7956, -122.4096)
    
    print(G)
    print(start_latlng[0], start_latlng[1])
    print(end_latlng[0], end_latlng[1])
    
    # find the nearest node to the start location
    orig_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, start_latlng[0], start_latlng[1])# find the nearest node to the end location
    dest_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, end_latlng[0], end_latlng[1])#  find the shortest path
    print(orig_node)
    print(dest_node)
    shortest_route = nx.shortest_path(G, orig_node, dest_node, method='bellman-ford')
    print(shortest_route)
```

Comment: @gboeing I have the problem that the function doesn't return what I want and I don't know how to fix it. I have read the documentation and I don't know why it gives an error.

Comment: @gboeing The code he used comes from the following Medium article: https://towardsdatascience.com/visualization-in-python-finding-routes-between-points-2d97d4881996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the documentation for the [nearest_nodes](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes) function. You're swapping the positions of the X and Y (ie, lng and lat coordinates) arguments you're passing in.